# How to run wordpress on localhost and django on localhost/product?

Tags: python, django, wordpress, nginx

I have developed a wordpress website for a product.And the product is made using django.So after the user logs in ,i have to redirect him to the django project.I have to achieve this on the same domain.I have nginx installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

- www.egwordpress.com (your Wordpress)
- egproduct.egwordpress.com (your Django app)
- NGinx config

  ```
  server {
      listen      80  default_server;

      server_name www.egwordpress.com;

      location / {
          root        /path/to/your/wordpress;
          index       index.html;
          try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
  }
  server {
      listen      80;

      server_name egproduct.egwordpress.com;

      location /api/ {    # your django product app
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000; # change port following your Django config
      }
  }
  ```